# Is there a way to get Firestore data in regular adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, android-viewmodel

I have a recyclerview adapter where I am binding data from an api call and displaying it. Data such as "Restaurant Name", "Restaurant Address", "Restaurant Rating", etc.
Pretty simple.

Here is where I'm a bit stuck. I just realized that I have to add "Count" to that same recyclerview. The "Count" reflects the number of users that are going to eat at that Restaurant Today. My problem is, "Count" is a field in my User Restaurant Documents from my Firestore Database so I have to add that to my "standard/regular" recyclerview adapter (as opposed to a Firestore Adapter).

I tried just getting the firestore data in the actual adapter but I know this is not the proper way to do it and it's not the adapter's responsibility.

TLDR; I'm wondering if there is a way to add firestore data to a REGULAR ADAPTER, not a FIRESTORE ADAPTER .

Thanks!!

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I modified it and removed the code. Hopefully this is simplified enough.